# How To Add Comparison Check For SMS number

Tags: android, python, python-2.7, android-intent, python-3.x

```
import android 
droid = android.Android() 
SMSmsgs = droid.smsGetMessages(False, 'inbox').result 
for message in SMSmsgs: 
    print 'From: '+message['address']+' > '+message['body']+'\n'
```

I need to add a check in this code for finding if sms is from desired/required number

Answer (score -1):

On the OnReceive method of the BroadcastReceiver you can use the below piece of code to find the sender.

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //---get the SMS message passed in---
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
            String sender = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
            // Your logic here to find the match
        }
}
```

Comment: i need in python language